# How to differentiate and make a else if condition in c# if 2 or 3 table contains same column names to convert it as a datasets

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datatables, dataset

1. I have 3 tables named: `student_List`, `Student_detail`, and `student_Record`. These tables have 2 columns with the same name:
   `Stud_Name`, `stud_Address`, but they store different data. I need an  `else if` condition to read the three tables and extract their datasets.
2. If I have 2 tables and the 1st one has `stud_Name` as the first column and `stud_Address` as the second column, and the 2nd one has columns vice versa (but same column names), is there any condition to differentiate them based on the order ?

As it stand now, I wrote 3 `else if` condition as below to read these 3 tables and extract datasets, but as they have the same column names I'm not sure how to write the condition.

```
else if (dt.columns.contains("Stud_Name") && dt.columns.contains("stud_Address))
{
    ds.tables[i].TableName="student_List";
}
```

Comment: Why not use union like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/SFX210Jm)?

Comment: Hi, I need to read datatables and convert it to datasets in c# code

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on the order of columns in a table as part of your schema. Why not simply alias them? `SELECT SL.Stud_Name AS SL_stud_name FROM student_List SL`

Comment: Please paste syntax checked code, only: Trailing quotes are missing from `"stud_Address`. (`"Stud_Address"` or `"stud_Name"`?!)